# Why is my awk sub command failing?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

When I run

```
df -hl | grep '/dev/disk1' | awk '{sub(/%/, \"\");print $5}'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
    {sub(/%/, >>>  \ <<< "\");}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on awk sub.

```
df -hl | grep '/dev/disk1'
```

returns

```
/dev/disk1                         112Gi   94Gi   18Gi    85% 24672655 4649071   84%   /
```

As I understand, it should return the percentage of disk space used.

It should return 85 from the input

```
/dev/disk1                         112Gi   94Gi   18Gi    85% 24699942 4621784   84%   /
```

Comment: It should return 85 from the input  /dev/disk1                         112Gi   94Gi   18Gi    85% 24699942 4621784   84%   /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will fix the command as you supplied it.
`df -hl | grep '/dev/disk1' | awk '{sub( /%/, ""); print $5 }'` 
No need to escape the double quotes.

Of course you don't need to use grep here either.
`df -hl | awk '/disk1/ { sub( /%/, "", $5); print $5}'`

Notice that you can supply the target for the substitution as a third argument to `sub`.

The sub command is described in the gawk manual [on this page.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: No need to use both `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can reduce it down to just df and awk with:

```
df --output=pcent /dev/disk1 | awk '/ /{printf("%d\n", $1)}'
```